# Why is compiling latex in OSX significantly slower than on linux, in a virtual machine, on the same computer?

Tags: mac, linux, performance

I have a computer with OSX Mavericks (10.9) running on it, as well as a debian wheezy VM on the same machine, assigned a conservative 2/8 of the cores, and 4Gb/16Gb ram.

On the VM I have texlive-base and dependencies installed, plus maybe a couple non-dependencies which I cannot remember now, but can find out it it matters. On OSX I have both mactex and 'texlive' via ports.

Counter intuitively, compiling latex documents is significantly faster in linux (the VM), than in OSX, where I tried both the installed distributions.

Following are the timings for a compile of this [file](http://www.ams.jhu.edu/~ers/learn-latex/paper.tex) (note: to compile you will also need [this file](http://www.ams.jhu.edu/~ers/learn-latex/doodle.eps)) with the macports latex and the debian latex. Note hoe the debian latex is about 2.5 times faster. I have not compiled this file with the mactex distribution, but I found that it is about 5x slower even than the macports one. My question is, why is either of them so slow?

## Linux:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012/Debian)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./paper.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, lo
aded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/dvips.def)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsthm.sty) (./paper.aux)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: dvips
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd) [1] [2] [3]
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omscmr.fd)

LaTeX Warning: Citation `amsldoc' on page 4 undefined on input line 275.

[4] [5] [6] [7] [8]

LaTeX Warning: Citation `amsldoc' on page 9 undefined on input line 579.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `amsthdoc' on page 9 undefined on input line 579.


Overfull \hbox (1.28pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 605--612
\OT1/cmr/m/n/12 struc-ture. For ex-am-ple, this sec-tion is la-beled us-ing the
 com-mand []\OT1/cmtt/m/n/12 \label{sect:cross-ref}\OT1/cmr/m/n/12 .
[9]

LaTeX Warning: Citation `knuth84' on page 10 undefined on input line 649.

<doodle.eps> [10]

LaTeX Warning: Citation `lamport' on page 11 undefined on input line 774.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `amsldoc' on page 11 undefined on input line 776.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `amsthdoc' on page 11 undefined on input line 777.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `latex-companion' on page 11 undefined on input line 77
9.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `math-into-latex' on page 11 undefined on input line 78
0.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `kopka03' on page 11 undefined on input line 780.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `latex-graphics' on page 11 undefined on input line 781
.

[11]

LaTeX Warning: Citation `knuth84' on page 12 undefined on input line 784.

No file paper.bbl.
[12] (./paper.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.

 )
(see the transcript file for additional information)
Output written on paper.dvi (12 pages, 35156 bytes).
Transcript written on paper.log.
latex paper.tex >&2  0.02s user 0.06s system 98% cpu 0.081 total
```

## OSX:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/MacPorts 2013_5)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./paper.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9f> and hyphenation patterns for 43 languages loaded.
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/size12.clo))
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty)
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty))
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg)
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics/dvips.def)))
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty)
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/amscls/amsthm.sty) (./paper.aux)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: dvips
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd) [1] [2] [3]
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/omscmr.fd)

LaTeX Warning: Citation `amsldoc' on page 4 undefined on input line 275.

[4] [5] [6] [7] [8]

LaTeX Warning: Citation `amsldoc' on page 9 undefined on input line 579.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `amsthdoc' on page 9 undefined on input line 579.


Overfull \hbox (1.28pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 605--612
\OT1/cmr/m/n/12 struc-ture. For ex-am-ple, this sec-tion is la-beled us-ing the
 com-mand []\OT1/cmtt/m/n/12 \label{sect:cross-ref}\OT1/cmr/m/n/12 .
[9]

LaTeX Warning: Citation `knuth84' on page 10 undefined on input line 649.

<doodle.eps> [10]

LaTeX Warning: Citation `lamport' on page 11 undefined on input line 774.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `amsldoc' on page 11 undefined on input line 776.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `amsthdoc' on page 11 undefined on input line 777.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `latex-companion' on page 11 undefined on input line 77
9.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `math-into-latex' on page 11 undefined on input line 78
0.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `kopka03' on page 11 undefined on input line 780.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `latex-graphics' on page 11 undefined on input line 781
.

[11]

LaTeX Warning: Citation `knuth84' on page 12 undefined on input line 784.

No file paper.bbl.
[12] (./paper.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.

 )
(see the transcript file for additional information)
Output written on paper.dvi (12 pages, 35156 bytes).
Transcript written on paper.log.
latex paper.tex >&2  0.14s user 0.02s system 77% cpu 0.209 total
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your OSX is 64 bit; is your Debian 32 bit?  That could be one reason.  However, your execution times are very small to draw definite conclusions.  If you want to study this, I suggest that you try latex-ing something much longer and that you benchmark it properly, e.g., executing it many times repeatedly on both machines and taking the average execution time.

Comment: also what does `kpsexpand '$TEXINPUTS'` report on both systems? if `/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/` is not prefixed by `!!` in the OSX version then TeX has to search the file system for each file which can be slow,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle coud you elaborate on that? I'm rather interested in this myself, since typesetting long documents using the `subfile` package feels somewhat slow. I'm on OS X as well using MacTex as my TeX-distro.

Comment: @Argo tex can prehash its search path using commands variously called `texhash` or `mktexlsr` it is basically just a recursive `ls -lR` file list, but searching the file is a _lot_ quicker than making file system calls to search all the directory tree. `!!` in a search path means _only_ consult the hashed file list never search the filesystem. Usually local directory and perhaps ~/texmf are not hashed so that files you just made are found, but if you have thousands of files in a tree without `!!` at the start of your path tex has to check that directory structure every time it looks for a file

Comment: @nickie,
The VM is 64bit. These times are quite consistent between runs, with maybe 10-20% variation. I would expect OSX to be at least as fast as a linux VM (and actually would expect it to be significantly faster).
Also, I do have a kind-of benchmark - previewing latex fragments in org buffers in emacs is much slower on OSX.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, Both OSX and linux have some paths with !! in front, and some without. In particular, the path you mentioned _is_ prefixed.

Comment: By the way, MacTeX *is* TeX Live with some extras so there is no point having an additional TeX Live installation. But you are not comparing like with like. The native installation of TL you show is a full distribution of TeX (or at least closer to it), whereas the one in the VM is more minimal. So TeX is reading more files in the former case than the latter. Look at the number of hyphenation patterns loaded, for example.

Comment: @cfr there *was* a point: testing for differences in speed. Installing both already paid off since (if you believe my claim), the macports version is ~5 times faster than the mactex version. Of course now that I know that, I can delete the mactex version... Are there characteristics other than the number of languages you saw that make you say the one on OSX is much fuller than the other? is the # of languages enough, alone, to account for the doubling in speed?

Comment: You are comparing TL2012 (Linux) with TL2013 (OSX). Please first make sure that both systems have the same TeX installations, ideally by installing vanilla TL2013 on both.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Comment: @martinschroeder what are you talking about? I have always had a nick. I'm sorry if it doesn't suit you that it isn't my full name. Anyway, thanks for the suggestion but it is quite a maintenance nightmare to maintain stuff outside the package managers of the respective OSs. Do you claim that the difference in versions could account for more than a little of the (over 100%) time difference?

Comment: The number of languages is probably only part of it. You said that one was little more than `texlive-base` plus dependencies. You don't say how the macports installation compares but it may well lie somewhere in between the VM installation and the MacTeX version which is probably a full installation of TeX Live. So you are comparing apples and oranges and would be even if they were both the same version (e.g. 2012 or 2013). Note that some documents will simply fail to compile at all in the VM but will compile fine with MacTeX. There are just too many variables here...

Comment: @cfr Actually, I found texlive-base (on debian) to be quite full featured for my needs (Mathematics) - and it also seemed like it pulled in most of the packages except for the languages. I didn't even really need the extra packages yet - just thought it might be useful to have them... In any case, I understand from all of this that you claim that the amount of packages can account for this order of magnitude difference (and somewhat more, accounting for debian being in a VM). It is surprising to me, but so be it - if it indeed is what you are claiming! Thanks!

Comment: I am not claiming that at all. I am saying that you cannot tell what is causing it because there are too many different variables. To get a fair comparison, you'd need to compare like with like. The languages will make some difference since the hyphenation patterns must be loaded from files. How much difference? No idea. But you are also using different versions of TL. Moreover, the size of the database of files TeX searches will be different. (It is not searching the tree, so this will be minimised but you are talking about small differences.) You'd need to test a longer document, too.

Comment: @cfr If you are not claiming that, then why does it matter? I'm not interested in the 10-20% differences, but rather by the 100-900% differences... If I told you that I am now using the same packages and still observe this difference, then what would you check next? Because I actually reinstalled texlive-basic on OSX, along with the minimum macports packages required to compile my files, and I get now less than 100%, but still maybe 80% time difference. What would you say is the cause now? Or are you just saying that because it is not exactly the same software, all hope for comparing is lost??

Comment: The point is it *might* matter and it is not possible to tell what matters without doing more systematic investigations as there are just too many factors involved. For example, what command exactly are you using to time things in the two cases? Do you know if those are equivalent? Have you compared timing for a longer document which takes a while to compile? The times here are too small to be of much use unless you repeat the tests over many runs. Etc. etc.

Comment: @cfr I would be happy to try a longer document, but the longest I could find all tool less than a second. I use the exact same command in bose cases (time latex -interaction=nonstopmode /path/to/file.tex). Although I did not get a longer document, and understand that it would be best to test on such one as well, I did try running the command by hand several tens of times, and the times have very small variations on both systems, and are closer to my intended use case anyway (which is previewing many equation latex fragments in a file while editing it).

Comment: Are you using the same shell in both cases? If I `time` something, for example, I get a slightly different format for output specifying `real`, `user` and `sys` time but no %. If I specify the path, I get a different format again. I get consistently different results for the same command, too, just by changing the version of `time` I'm using. For a longer document, how about compiling the `tikz` manual or something?

Comment: @cfr, I am using the same shell in both cases. I'm not sure exactly what you mean when you say "If I specify the path". And what versions of time are you talking about? as in, in different shells? I will try compiling the manual, and report my findings. Thanks!

Comment: To specify the path, you write something like `/usr/bin/time...` rather than just `time`. `time` is probably using the shell's builtin command (at least for bash). Obviously the `time` command might be located somewhere different on your system. But there's still the question of which version of `time` you are using. `man time` should give you details for the path-specified version. `man bash` may say something for the builtin version.

Comment: Recently, I switched back from Arch Linux on a MacbookPro to Max OS X and I can confirm the notable time difference in compiling .tex documents. I would also be interested what's the reason for this.